# How to loop through optparse.OptionGroup in Python

Tags: python, python-2.6, optparse

I am trying to loop through a certain group of parameters ('-p' only).
I declare them as follows in the terminal: `python program.py -p paramOne paramTwo`. My program output is only `paramOne` and I do not understand why. My goal is to get the following output:

```
paramOne
paramTwo
```

Can anyone tell me where the error in my code is?

Here is the code:

```
# Parcing definitions
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
groupParam = optparse.OptionGroup(parser, 'Output handling')
parser.add_option('-q', '--quiet', action='store_false', dest='verbose', default=True,
                help=('don\'t print status messages to stdout'))
groupParam.add_option('-p', '--parameters', action='store', dest='paramNum', type='string', 
                help=('specify number of parameters (Optional)'))

parser.add_option_group(groupParam)

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()


for groupParam1 in groupParam.option_list:
    print getattr(options, groupParam1.dest)
```

P.S. I am running Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify `nargs`, it uses `1` as a default value; consuming only one positional argument.

Specify `nargs=2` to get 2 values:

```
groupParam.add_option(
    '-p', '--parameters', action='store', dest='paramNum', type='string',
    nargs=2,  # <---
    help=('specify number of parameters (Optional)')
)
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.nargs):

> How many arguments of type type should be consumed when this option is
>   seen. **If > 1, optparse will store a tuple of values to dest.**

so, the last loop should be modified to check `tuple` to print as you wanted:

```
for groupParam1 in groupParam.option_list:
    values = getattr(options, groupParam1.dest)
    if isinstance(values, tuple):
        for value in values:
            print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This indeed works, but (I did not mention), my arguments will be dynamic (0 - about 20), so how can `nargs` be dynamic?

Comment: @Newskooler, You need to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) to use dynamic nargs (`?`, `*`, `+`), but unfortunately, it's available in Python 2.7+. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs